# SELECT DISTINCT multiple values from a single cell

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Let's say I have the following table, called `test`:

[image]

Executing the query `SELECT DISTINCT category FROM test ORDER BY category;` will output:

[image]

When changing a value as follows:

[image]

…and calling the query `SELECT DISTINCT category FROM test ORDER BY category;` again, I'll get:

[image]

But I want to get the following instead:

[image]

Is there a way to do this in SQL? Or should I do this directly in my PHP?

Comment: Most people where want formatted text, not images.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Noooooooooo. See normalisation

Comment: When you edit your query, write sample data in proper columns. Mark them and click `{}`.

Comment: Don't put A and F together in one row. One category per row is the SQL way.

Comment: @jarlh Means: If I want to have five categories, I'll need five category columns?

Comment: I'd rather consider two rows for the apple. One A and one F.

Comment: @jarlh Unfortunately this doesn't make sense in my case, because it's just a senseless duplicate. P.S. I real there are more rows with multiple categories. What do you suggest? Is creating multiple category columns recommended in my case?

Comment: I created a second column `category2` and am using this code: `SELECT DISTINCT category FROM test WHERE category != "U"
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT category2 FROM test WHERE category2 != "U" ORDER BY category;`. Seems to work. Is this recommended? Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You should have 3 tables here. One will hold the the categories, the other one will hold the items and the final one will hold the relations between categories and items (it is also known as [associative table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity)):

```
categories: id name
items: id name
categories_items: category_id item_id
```

Your query in this case will become:

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM categories 
ORDER BY name;
```

If you want to get all items from a category you could do:

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM items 
JOIN categories_items 
  ON items.id = categories_items.item_id
 AND categories_items.category_id = 4;
```

Comment: Why that? Why would it help? I think it doesn't make really sense for me because most categories are different.

Comment: I created a second column `category2` and am using this code: `SELECT DISTINCT category FROM test WHERE category != "U"
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT category2 FROM test WHERE category2 != "U" ORDER BY category;`. Seems to work. Is this recommended? Does it make sense?

Comment: The answer to your question could be the first statement I wrote. What do you think? Which one looks much more optimized? You  must avoid using union as much as possible as it may cause a lot of performance bottlenecks

Answer (score 0):

You should definetely normalize your tables but if you still insist on this table structure, you can try this query:

```
WITH CatChar(aChar, remain) AS (
   SELECT LEFT(category,1), RIGHT(category, LEN(category)-1) 
      FROM test WHERE LEN(category)>0
   UNION ALL
   SELECT LEFT(remain,1), RIGHT(remain, LEN(remain)-1) FROM CatChar
      WHERE LEN(remain)>0
)
SELECT DISTINCT aChar FROM CatChar
```

(Assuming your all category names are just one char length, otherwise you should reorganeze `LEFT(...)` part to split according to your separator)

Comment: I created a second column `category2` and am using this code: `SELECT DISTINCT category FROM test WHERE category != "U"
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT category2 FROM test WHERE category2 != "U" ORDER BY category;`. Seems to work. Is this recommended? Does it make sense?

Comment: If you sure that there wont be third category, It can be used. But you should read about normalization and denormalization concepts